# Spring boot actuator "/health" is not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have a running Springboot application which serves the URL `http://localhost:8081/topics` and returns me JSON response as expected.

I added actuator dependency 

`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>`

as suggested in [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ojc_Jy_0EgI&list=PLqq-6Pq4lTTbx8p2oCgcAQGQyqN8XeA1x)

But when I hit `http://localhost:8081/health` it does not give expected result. It says

`{
    "timestamp": 1497952368055,
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/health"
}`

Spring boot version  is 1.5.4.RELEASE. And Java 1.8
What additional settings do I need to do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your dependency you have declared

```
<scope>test</scope>
```

It means that

> **test**
>
> This scope indicates that the dependency is not required for normal
>   use of the application, and is only available for the test compilation
>   and execution phases.

If you want it available for normal use of the application remove `<scope>test</scope>` or change it to `<scope>compile</scope>`

Comment: Also, you need to disable spring security for some actuator endpoints.

Comment: Actuator health checks have now moved to the endpoint /actuator/health. See https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-consul/issues/345

Answer (score 25):

In Spring Boot 2.0.0 you have to use `/actuator/health`
and in the **application.properties** file add the following line:

```
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
```

Answer (score 8):

Do the following steps : -

1. Change the scope of actuator dependency from `test` to `compile`
2. Instead of using `/health` use `/actuator/health`
3. If you want to see **details** of the health status then add`management.endpoint.health.show-details=always` in the `application.properties file`.

Answer (score 6):

**Add Maven dependency**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**Application.properties**

`management.endpoints.web.exposure.include= "*"`  *include all endpoints on* actuator
or
`management.endpoints.web.exposure.include= health`  *if need only health endpoint*

Answer (score 1):

Maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Application.properties

```
spring.profiles.active=local
server.port = 9292
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=env,health,metrics
```

For reference use below link:(step by step explanation)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Dj2tsK2V2g

Answer (score 0):

If still not working for :

1. Select project the rth click
2. Run as maven build
3. Goals - clean install them ok

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have added a context path.

if yes, you need to try ->

> http://localhost:8080/{{serviceName}}/actuator/health

And check the following in either `.properties` or `.yaml` file :

- `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include = *`  : if you want to include all endpoints on actuator
- `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include = health` : if you need only health endpoint