# Spring Cloud Dataflow - Stream deployment stuck in "Deploying"

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-skipper

My Custom stream is stuck in "Deploying". But the stream is actually working. Messages are received by the sink. But the status in SCDF is "Deploying".
Per query - [Spring Cloud Dataflow Custom App stuck in Deploying state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54315857/spring-cloud-dataflow-custom-app-stuck-in-deploying-state) @Sabby Anandan said, SCDF checks `/health` and `/info`. But per this post [Spring boot actuator "/health" is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44649988/spring-boot-actuator-health-is-not-working) the URL should be `actuator/health`. This is consistent with my code as well. `http://localhost:1234/health` does not work, but `http://localhost:1234/actuator/health` gives me `{"status":"UP"}`

This is a bug in SCDF? should it check for `actuator/health`. 
Can you please help? If this is a bug, do I have any workaround?
Below are the version details:

-SCDF - spring-cloud-dataflow-server-2.5.1.BUILD-20200518.143034-16

-Skipper - spring-cloud-skipper-server-2.4.1.BUILD-20200518.094106-12

-Boot - 2.3.0

Comment: Just to note: You are using Spring Boot 2.3.0 but SCDF 2.5.x uses 2.2.x. I haven't checked if the endpoints changed in Spring Boot 2.3.x but I suspect that could also be a reason.

Comment: Ilayaperumal Gopinathan - I tried with 2.2.7 and it still it did not work.